# Recompile kernel without modules that are not currently in use

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Is there a neat way of stripping the Linux kernel to only support the devices that are currently in use. After NVIDIA complaining about GCC version mismatch, I decided to recompile the kernel with the current version of GCC. Now, since it is known which modules the current kernel actually uses, can I automatically generate a `.config` file which is customized for this machine. That would booth save some space and time. Something like

```
lsmod [options] | sed [a good regexp] > .config
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what `make localmodconfig` is for.

Excerpt from `/usr/src/linux/README`:

> ```
> "make localmodconfig" Create a config based on current config and
>                       loaded modules (lsmod). Disables any module
>                       option that is not needed for the loaded modules.
> ```