# Determine minimum kernel options for your hardware

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I know this is totally unnecessary, but I like the idea of determining exactly what modules my hardware needs and running a kernel with only those in it and no more.

However, in the massive plethora of kernel options, determining exactly what I need seems somewhat of a daunting task.

Are there any programs to help with this? Is there a standard process for determining what modules are currently actually in use rather than just available for use?

Comment: Does this answer your question or is it more to it? [Recompile kernel without modules that are not currently in use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218834)

Comment: I suppose that depends on whether you have any kernel modules loaded that aren't actually needed? I'm not entirely sure how kernel module loading works in that regard